# CoCreateInstance - The COM+ registry database detected a system error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com, com+

In a small test project I have this code:

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof( IXMLDOMDocument ), ( void ** ) & m_pDoc);
if ( hr != S_OK )
{
  throw "MSXML DOM Document could not be created";
}
```

This compiles and runs without problems. In another project the same code fails with:

hr = 0x80110474 The COM+ registry database detected a system error

Both projects are C++ compiled using Visual Studio 2010. I've been through and compared settings side-by-side between the two projects to try and determine what difference could be causing this issue. So far I can see no reason why the test project runs and the other project fails.

Edit - Full sample code listing:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
#include "MsXml.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IXMLDOMDocument* m_pDoc = NULL;
    if(FAILED(CoInitializeEx( 0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED )))
      if(FAILED(CoInitializeEx( 0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED )))
        throw "Could not initialize COM";
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_DOMDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof( IXMLDOMDocument ), ( void ** ) & m_pDoc);
    if ( hr != S_OK )
      throw "MSXML DOM Document could not be created";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How have you registered the component with Class ID CLSID_DOMDocument? And how have you referenced it in both the projects?

Comment: CLSID_DOMDocument is part of Microsoft's MSXML package. And was installed using their installer.

Comment: This is a pre-installed component in Windows, be sure to never install it yourself.  Why this generates a COM+ error is unguessable from the code snippet.  Assuming that the registry on that machine is in poor shape is probably a good guess.

Comment: @Hans - As per the description the code snippet works in one project, but not another. I doubt it has anything to do with a corrupt registry!

Comment: The HRESULT in question is COMADMIN_E_REGDB_SYSTEMERR.  Corrupt or not the problem almost certainly has something to do with the registry.  Something is leading the COM infrastructure to believe there is something wrong with the registration of this COM object.  

Are you running these tests on a 64-bit system?  If you are, are the working and failing tests both 32-bit (or both 64-bit)?  If not then differences between the 'real' registry and SysWow64 might be causing your problems.

Comment: @Frank - No, it's on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine. If it's a registry problem, why does it only happen in one particular project.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, although not ideal it solved the problem. I created a new project and manually imported the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with Turbo Delphi: the same code with CoCreateInstance() works in one project and fails in another one with HR=80110474 (COMADMIN_E_REGDB_SYSTEMERR). It was caused by IDE overriding environment variables which are stored in project settings. So it fails only when being runned under IDE (regardless of debugging state). Cleaning up project settings resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've spent all night trying to debug this problem. In my case no file dialogs would open. Unfortunately, I need to override an environment variable to work around a bug in Delphi's build scripts... Just can't win.